# Memoization of a function of various inputs in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, memoization

I have a costly function taking various `double` variables as inputs:

```
public double f(double v1, double v2, double v3){
    ...
    return output;
}
```

So I tried to memoise its output, using two different strategies.

#### Nested HashMaps:

```
Map<Double,Map<Double,Map<Double,Double>>> map = new HashMap<>();

public double f(double v1, double v2, double v3){
    // This is abbreviated: in my case I made sure to call only once each "get()"
    if(map.containsKey(v1) && map.get(v1).containsKey(v2) && map.get(v1).get(v2).containsKey(v3))
         return map.get(v1).get(v2).get(v3);
    ...
    // calculations
    ...
    // put "output" in the map (and create new intermediate HashMaps when needed)
    ...
    return output;
}
```

#### Custom HashMap key:

```
public class DoubleKey {
   public final double[] values;
   public DoubleKey(double[] values){ this.values = values;}

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object key){
      if(key instanceof DoubleKey)
         return Arrays.equals(values, ((DoubleKey)key).values);
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashcode(){
      return Arrays.hashcode(values);
   }
}

Map<DoubleKey,Double> map = new HashMap<>();

public double f(double v1, double v2, double v3){
    DoubleKey key = new DoubleKey(new double[]{v1,v2,v3});
    if(map.containsKey(key))
         return map.get(key);
    ...
    // calculations
    ...
    map.put(key, output);
    return output;
}
```

---

Now, I expected the second approach to be faster, as it uses a single Hashmap, and feels generally more elegant. But it turns out that I gain less benefit from the second method, compared to the first method which yields a great speed boost.

Do you know why would the second method be less efficient? Is it the cost of using `Arrays.equals()` and/or `Arrays.hashcode()`?

More generally, do you know of other memoization techniques that would be more efficient?

Comment: java.lang.Object calculates hash code only once and store it. I think you should use this approach too. Also it is more efficient add three double fields instead of array.

Comment: Also you can use something more efficient than regular java collections for storing primitive types like TObjectDoubleMap from http://trove.starlight-systems.com/

Comment: Please define *efficient*.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, I mean "fast"

Comment: @sibnick, Thanks for the tip! I tried storing the hashcode, but it did not make a big change.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth How did you measure the performance? Also you could improve a little by replacing containsKey + get by get + null check.

Comment: @assylias, I measured execution time (in ms) of a program that makes many calls to `f()`. I run the same program about ten times with the same inputs and take an average (excluding the first call which is way more expensive).

Comment: @EricLeibenguth Your measurement may be incorrect - you should build a proper benchmark, for example using jmh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two solutions are not equal. the first one hard coded support only 3 double args while the second one supports any number of args.

if you need to support only exactly 3 args, I think it is more efficient to hold 3 instance variables:

**EDIT:** following comments, replaced original answer that used varargs ctor with explicit individual args. probably more efficient (does not construct aray). also made instance vars final to enable compiler optimization

```
public class DoubleKey
{
    final double arg1, arg2, arg3;
    final int hashCode;

    public DoubleKey(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3)
    {
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
        this.arg3 = arg3;
        hashCode = Objects.hash(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object key)
    {
        if (key instanceof DoubleKey) {
            DoubleKey dk = (DoubleKey) key;
            return arg1 == dk.arg1 && arg2 == dk.arg2 && arg3 == dk.arg3;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

constructing DoubleKey instance is now preatier

`DoubleKey key = new DoubleKey(v1,v2,v3);`

Comment: why not `public DoubleKey(double value1, double value2, double value3) {...}` ?

Comment: and how would you calcaulate one hashCode?

Comment: I don't know what is the efficiency of commons HashCodeBuilder and I don't know how to construct hash code out of 3 double values. would be glad to see though

Comment: E.g. `long tmp = Double.doubleToLongBits(v1) ^ Double.doubleToLongBits(v2) ^ Double.doubleToLongBits(v3); int hash = (int)((tmp>>>32) ^tmp);`

Comment: _efficiency of commons HashCodeBuilder_  The likelihood of it being an issue is tiny. I'd say worrying about the efficiency of a commonly used API is a waste, you could be working on features. 
But then I would have just used one of the [many](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-cacheable.html) [existing](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/) [caching](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) [solutions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) rather than rolling my own.
`@Cached public Whatever boo();` Sorted.

Comment: fine, then OP can change the ctor as the first comment mentions and implement hash code according to the suggestions in comments

Comment: on the topic of existing caching solutions, my preferred one is [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)

Comment: (y) It is a good one. Does it have an memorize annotation for Java?

Comment: it has [Spring 3 Annotations](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/spring-annotations)

Comment: @assylias, thanks. probably best solution (certainly most elegant). will edit answer to reflect this